Django form dynamically created fields miss from cleaned_data
I'm trying to implement dynamic fields in ModelForm using AJAX requests.
I have a cameras_num custom field as IntegerField. Once user picks value AJAX passes cameras_num field's value to ModelForm with kwargs and generates forms.ModelChoiceField with names camera_{number} ("camera_1", "camera_2" ... "camera_3").
However when form submits form.data contains all "cameras" (lets say {"camera_1": [1], "camera_2": [2]}) while form.cleaned_data contains only one camera ("camera_1").
class ConfigurationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cameras_qty = kwargs.pop('cameras_qty', 1)
        super(ConfigurationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if cameras_qty:
            for camera_num in range(1, cameras_qty+1):
                self.fields[f"camera_{camera_num}"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                    label=f"Camera {camera_num}",
                    queryset=models.Camera.objects.all()
                )

    cameras_num = forms.IntegerField(
        widget=forms.Select(choices=[(i,i) for i in range(1, 4)]),
        initial=1
    )

view.py:
def create_device_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        device_config_form = forms.ConfigurationForm(request.POST)
        # here device_config_form.data contains all "cameras"
        if device_config_form.is_valid():
            # here only "camera_1" exists in device_config_form.cleaned_data
            device_config_form.save()
            return redirect(reverse("device_list", kwargs={"status": "all"}))
    else:
        device_config_form = forms.ConfigurationForm()
        if is_ajax(request):
            # cameras
            cameras_qty = request.GET.get("cameras_qty")
            if cameras_qty and isinstance(cameras_qty, str):
                cameras_data = []
                # passing cameras qty received from GET parameters
                device_config_form = forms.ConfigurationForm(cameras_qty=int(cameras_qty))
                for field_name in device_config_form.fields.keys():
                    if field_name.startswith("camera_"):
                        camera_field = (
                            device_config_form[field_name].label_tag(),
                            str(device_config_form[field_name])
                            )
                        cameras_data.append(camera_field)
                return JsonResponse(
                    data={"success": True, "cameras": cameras_data},
                    safe=False
                )
                
    return render(
        request,
        "production/device_create.html",
        {"device_config_form": device_config_form})


Share the view where you use the form.

@willeM_VanOnsem I've added view.py as per your request. However data missed on is_valid() call.

@Anthony_K: the forms.ConfigurationForm(request.POST) does not contain a value for the cameras_qty parameter?

@willeM_VanOnsem it contains cameras_num field. cameras_qty instead used as **kwargs argument passed to form on GET request.
HTML string from device_config_form = forms.ConfigurationForm(request.POST) doesn't contain any other cameras except camera_1 as well while device_config_form.data does. What am I missing?

but kwargs.get('cameras_num', 1) will thus return 1. The fact that there is a form field with that number does not matter.

That being said, what you are trying to do, to some extent, already exists, this is a FormSet.

@willeM_VanOnsem I'm aware of FormSets but I wouldn't like to use that for a "single" field if there is another way. I'm missing your point regards cameras_num as form by default provides camera_num = 1 for GET requests except those GET requests with explicit camera_num parameter.  I want to figure out why rest of cameras missing on POST validation.
